# aggregating repeat entries prior to summarizing on other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,3,4,3,1,1,2),event=c('a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b'),var1=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),var2=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0),var_total=c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1))
df
   id event var1 var2 var_total
1   1     a    1    1         1
2   2     a    1    0         1
3   3     a    0    0         0
4   4     a    0    0         0
5   3     a    1    1         1
6   4     a    0    1         1
7   3     a    1    0         1
8   1     b    1    1         1
9   1     b    0    1         1
10  2     b    1    0         1
```

I am reformatting/cleaning data from a data entry site that produces very diagonal data. I have got it into a manageable form at the moment, but I still have one problem. There are events that repeat, and I would like each id/event combination to be unique. As you can see, lines 5 and 6 are duplicate in that aspect, but the variables are not identical. The variables are a binary response (yes=1,no=0), but if there is any yes in the event the variable should be 1. Additionally, the 'var_total' column should be 1 if ANY of the variables are positive.

My data set has 77 of these 'repeat events' out of over 6000 entries, and it's likely to change everytime more data is entered. How do I isolate ids with repeat events so I can aggregate() (?summarise) them and be sure it's done correctly? There are over 15 variables. I need to report number of ids per event for all variables.

Comment: What is your intended output here? Just remove rows 5-6?

Comment: No, lol. I wish. I need to reconcile the data in rows 5-6 with 3-4 (eg, if one value is 1 the reconciled value needs to be 1 and the total needs to be 1). Similarly row 9 needs to be reconciled with row 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id, event) %>%
  summarize(
    across(var1:var2, ~ +any(. > 0)),
    var_total = +((var1 + var2) > 0),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  arrange(event, id)
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      id event  var1  var2 var_total
#   <dbl> <chr> <int> <int>     <int>
# 1     1 a         1     1         1
# 2     2 a         1     0         1
# 3     3 a         1     1         1
# 4     4 a         0     1         1
# 5     1 b         1     1         1
# 6     2 b         1     0         1
```

Notes:

- The `arrange` is purely getting it back to the order you had in your question, not required for the operation of the code.
- `summarize` is wiping out `var_total` and then recreating it based on the logic you stated (either `var*` is 1).
- I could have easily used `across(var1:var2, max)` instead of the `~ +any(. > 0)`, it produces the same results here. I shows the `~ any` version purely to demonstrating something a little more complex than `max`.

Comment: That works great. Thank you. What exactly does the '+' indicate? it's not summing, I know that, and I don't think it's part of a regex...

Comment: `+` is a shortcut for converting `FALSE` and `TRUE` to `0` and `1`, respectively.

Comment: so, "if var1 or var2 are greater than zero, read as TRUE and covert to 1"?

Comment: Yes, you got it right